# Error WAT080 : Failed to locate the Windows Azure SDK. Please make sure the Windows Azure SDK v2.0 is installed

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

I have installed the windows azure sdk2.0 manually from the following link
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=38797

I could  run my cloud project but when i added a new cloud project and try to compile it is giving build error 
Error  WAT080 : Failed to locate the Windows Azure SDK. Please make sure the Windows Azure SDK v2.0 is installed

I am unable to figure out the problem.Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your current azure, then install it again by using the Web Platform Installer .

Comment: What if you cannot use the WP Installer because of security reasons. Is there a way to do this stand-alone/offline?